# Python replace some part of string with asterisk

Tags: python, python-3.x, str-replace, mask, data-manipulation

I was making some kind of Lottery software, which show on live TV. I've phone number list (each number have 8 digits). I want hide last 2 digits for protect user privacy. Using python 3.

Current code sample:

```
for item in numbers:
    print(item)
```

List example:

```
88458932
88489325
84589328
83284589
83245898
83458289
```

Wanted result:

```
884589**
884893**
845893**
832845**
832458**
834582**
```

Comment: Is numbers a list? If yes, is it list of strings?

Comment: Are you asking type of variable? It's currently string. But it doesn't matter much. I can convert to any type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the phone numbers are represented by a string, you can generate a new string where the last chars are replaced by a star:

```
for item in numbers:
    covered = item[:-2] + '**'
    print(covered)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the world of quick implementations, this should work for you:

```
for item in numbers:
    print(item[:-2] + '**')
```